# Rails: How can I display successive user input in a text box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails novice here.  I want to build a very basic chat bot (no learning involved, simply query user input against DB) for a rails app and I'm trying to break the problem into pieces.

I can't figure out how to display subsequent user input on the same page like what you would see in a message window.

I found another post that contains the following code, but each successive input overrides the previous one, I'm assuming due to a new request each time that writes over the instance variable?

```
Controller.rb:

class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if params[:q].present?
     @input = "hello #{params[:q]}!"
    end
  end
end

form:

 <%= form_tag("/home", method: "get") do %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:q, @input) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
 <%= @input %>
```

The other objective here is I don't want to save any of the user inputs to the DB.  I want the 'chat session' to be temporary and once the user navigates away the displayed data is discarded.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a request is sent to your Rails server a new instance of the controller is made. Once a response has been sent, that instance is destroyed along with any instance variables it created. There really isn't any way to persist those previous messages without saving them to the DB. You could possibly try keeping track of each input in an array in `params[:q]`, appending the new message on the end and continually passing that array back and forth between client and server.

Comment: Could you show me the code for how to do this?  I originally figured an array would be the way to go, but couldn't successfully implement it.

Comment: Forgot to add, is it possible use the instance variable for my query and capture the messages in a Javascript array?  Then I would destroy the Javascript array upon navigation or some other action.

Comment: I am honestly not sure how to do it myself.